# validate password length after user leave password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords

I want to check if the password length is at least 8 characters or not, when the user leaves the password field or press tab key. 
How can i do this?

My code for password is shown below.

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="pass1" placeholder="password"/>
```

Comment: use on `blur`.........

Comment: Jai can you help me to write code ?

Comment: you can try the posted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the jquery `blur` method for this.

```
$('#pass1').on('blur', function(){
    if(this.value.length < 8){ // checks the password value length
       alert('You have entered less than 8 characters for password');
       $(this).focus(); // focuses the current field.
       return false; // stops the execution.
    }
});
```

#### [Fiddle for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8nE2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript onchange event as below

and script code callfunction() as

```
function callfunction()
{


     var textBox = document.getElementById("pass1");
       var textLength = textBox.value.length;

         if(textBox.value=='' || textLength<=8)
         {
          alert('Please enter correct password');
         }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#pass1').on('blur', function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 8){
      alert('safe!');
    }
});
```

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ACK2f/

Answer (score 0):

Password validation can use several rules, I used a service but the code inside the function can be reusable:

```
_validatePassword = function (validateUserNameRules, Model)
    {
        //bolean parameter validateUserNameRules -> true/false

        //this method recive a model like this:
        //Model.userName -> string
        //Model.password -> string
        //Model.password2 -> String

        var validationResult = {
            ResultId: 1, //1 success
            Message: "Password is correct."
            };

        if (validateUserNameRules && Model.userName == "") {

            validationResult.ResultId = 2;
            validationResult.Message = "Error: User name cannot be blank.";
            return (validationResult);
        }

        var re = /^\w+$/;
        if (validateUserNameRules && !re.test(Model.userName)) {

            validationResult.ResultId = 2;
            validationResult.Message = "Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.";
            return (validationResult);

        }

        if (Model.password != "" && Model.password == Model.password2) {
            if (Model.password.length < 6) {
                validationResult.ResultId = 2;
                validationResult.Message = "Error: Password must contain at least six characters.";
                return (validationResult);
            }
            if (validateUserNameRules && Model.password == Model.userName) {
                validationResult.ResultId = 2;
                validationResult.Message = "Error: Password must be different from the Account Name.";
                return (validationResult);
            }
            re = /[0-9]/;
            if (!re.test(Model.password)) {
                validationResult.ResultId = 2;
                validationResult.Message = "Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9).";
                return (validationResult);
            }
            re = /[a-z]/;
            if (!re.test(Model.password)) {

                validationResult.ResultId = 2;
                validationResult.Message = "Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z).";
                return (validationResult);

            }
            re = /[A-Z]/;
            if (!re.test(Model.password)) {

                validationResult.ResultId = 2;
                validationResult.Message = "Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z).";
                return (validationResult);
            }
        } else {
            validationResult.ResultId = 2;
            validationResult.Message = "Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password.";
            return (validationResult);
        }

        return (validationResult); //success password validation!!
    };
```